# how to add mouserightbuttondown event to stackpanel in silverlight 3

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

how to add mouserightbuttondown event to stackpanel in silverlight 3

Answer (score 0):

In Silverlight 3 its quite tricky,  probably the best solution all other things being equal is start using Silverlight 4.  However I guess you would if you could, so...

Take a look at this [blog](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/07/01/tip-of-the-day-14-how-to-right-click-on-a-silverlight-application.aspx) and in particular the contribution of code fome "scommisso"/

The fundemental idea is to enlist the host browsers oncontextmenu event then some hit testing to determine if the mouse is over your stackpanel.  Still has limitations and gotchas though.